# Why does the mode dial on my Canon camera set the wrong mode? (Av is P, M is C2, etc.)

Tags: canon, troubleshooting, camera-controls

I've had my Canon 5D Mark iii for quite some time but I just stumbled upon this really upsetting issue.

My Capturing mode wheel isn't displaying the right capture mode. When I place the dial on M, it sets the camera on C2 mode; the Av mode on P and so on. This happens to every single mode but Auto. I recently installed Magic Lantern in my camera; I hope this doesn't have anything to do with it. (The problem also now happens without Magic Lantern?)

Can I fix this, or does the camera need to be serviced?

Answer (score 3):

Magic Lantern isn't installed on your camera it is run from the SD card and is an *add-on* over your existing firmware. The first thing I would do is bypass Magic Lantern by pressing and holding SET at startup. If that doesn't work format the SD card in the camera.

If getting around Magic Lantern doesn't resolve the issue, it sounds like your hardware is faulty.

Comment: Or try a different SD card.

Comment: I already uninstalled ML and formated my CF but the problem still persists. And if its a hardware problem Im afraid the fact that I installed MF could void my warranty.

Comment: try updating the firmware. It sometimes resets many non-default camera settings.

Answer (score 2):

I've experience the same issue while repairing a 5D3, it came out that the issue was caused by the top cover flat cable not properly connecting to the main board of the camera. Solved by cleaning with isopropilc alchool the flat contacts. Hope this solution might help someone in the same trouble.